# Synchronous operation exception via File.ReadAllBytes() method

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, asynchronous

I created a short code, and I got this exception:

*Handle does not support **synchronous operations**. The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened asynchronously (that is, it was opened explicitly for overlapped I/O).*

The code is something like this:

```
byte[] filebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
List<byte> codedbytes = new List<byte>();
byte constbyte = 240;
int blocksize = 67108864;
int counter = 0;
List<int> tempindex = new List<int>();
int index = 0;

private void DoTheJob()
{

        [...]

        for (int i = 0; i < filebytes.Length; i++,counter++)
        {
            codedbytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToChar((filebytes[i] * constbyte))));
            if (counter == blocksize)
            {
                FileStream tempwriter = File.Create(startdir + "\\temp" + index.ToString() + ".file");

                for (int x = 0; x < codedbytes.Count; x++)
                {
                    tempwriter.WriteByte(codedbytes[x]);
                }

                tempwriter.Close();
                codedbytes.Clear();
                counter = 0; tempindex.Add(index); index++;
            }
        }

        [...]

        for (int x = 0; x < tempindex.Count; x++)
        {
            ▉Exception at this line▉▶ codedbytes = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(startdir + "\\temp" + tempindex[x].ToString() + ".file"));

            [...]
        }
}
```

I don't know what's the problem because the FileStrem class has no overloaded constructor, and I closed every object.

Please show me the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you're only closing the FileStream and not disposing the FileStream. I'm thinking there may be a resource associated with the file that is not released by close but may be with Dispose.  The constructor the exception is mentioning is probably the FileStream created when trying to perform File.ReadAllBytes.

Try this:

```
private void DoTheJob()
{

        [...]

        for (int i = 0; i < filebytes.Length; i++,counter++)
        {
            codedbytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToChar((filebytes[i] * constbyte))));
            if (counter == blocksize)
            {
                using (FileStream tempwriter = File.Create(startdir + "\\temp" + index.ToString() + ".file"))
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < codedbytes.Count; x++)
                    {
                        tempwriter.WriteByte(codedbytes[x]);
                    }               
                }

                codedbytes.Clear();
                counter = 0; tempindex.Add(index); index++;
            }
        }

        [...]

        for (int x = 0; x < tempindex.Count; x++)
        {
            codedbytes = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(startdir + "\\temp" + tempindex[x].ToString() + ".file"));

            [...]
        }
}
```